# Is the marked state for reviewed questions bleeding across to late answers?

Tags: support, review

I was reviewing a bunch of questions using the new close vote portion of the review tools.  When I went to the late answers tab after reviewing a number of questions, I only saw a handful of answers show up in the "late answers" tab for today, or even this week.

Normally, I see pages and pages of answers here.  Is it possible that when I review a question, it is marking a state that is then bleeding across to the late answers review?  That is, when I review a question and it is hidden, could a late answer at that same index be accidentally hidden for me as well, as if I had reviewed it?

Could there be something else going on that would be dramatically reducing the number of late answers showing up in the review tools?

Comment: I think if a question has been reviewed more than a couple times by other users  it does n't show up in review, perhaps this is why items aren't showing up in that menu?

Comment: This seems fairly sudden, though.  If that applied to the late answers, I would've expected to see a more gradual drop off in the number of items I'd see in review, assuming more people were reviewing late answers now.  They just all disappeared today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it does not bleed through that way.

However if 2 of your peers review an answer it is removed from your list. Since the peers have `Strunk & White` they are pretty trusted.

> Could there be something else going on that would be dramatically reducing the number of late answers showing up in the review tools?

**Yes** the community have started to use `/review` quite heavily, so the backlog is way smaller.

---

Some stats to back up this claim:

```
select p.Id
from Posts p 
join Posts q on q.Id = p.ParentId
join Users u on u.Id = p.OwnerUserId 
where p.PostTypeId = 2 and q.CreationDate < p.CreationDate - 30 and u.Reputation <= 10 and p.DeletionDate is null 
 and p.CreationDate > (GETUTCDATE() - 1) and p.Id not in (select PostId from UserPostReviews 
group by PostId 
having count(*) > 1) 
order by p.Id desc
```

returns **2 posts** at the moment.

```
select p.Id
from Posts p 
join Posts q on q.Id = p.ParentId
join Users u on u.Id = p.OwnerUserId 
where p.PostTypeId = 2 and q.CreationDate < p.CreationDate - 30 and u.Reputation <= 10 and p.DeletionDate is null 
 and p.CreationDate > (GETUTCDATE() - 1)
```

return **242**

In the last 24 hours we had a staggering **3966** reviews.

```
select count(*) from UserPostReviews
where CreationDate > (GETUTCDATE() - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the detailed stats.  I didn't know that other reviews removed items from the list, so that makes sense.  Perhaps the moderator election, with its badge requirements, spurred a few more people to look for things to flag. Hopefully this will last.