# Has the new reviewing interface and/or the badge objectively reduced spam and non-answers?

Tags: discussion, review, spam

Has the spam problem declined a lot since the new reviewing interface (or the badge) was introduced? I have hardly flagged anything as spam or "not an answer" since then, and not because I'd recently gotten the Marshal badge and could rest on my laurels or something. Are more people reviewing now? Is this something the underlying data can reveal?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An unconditional **Yes**.

[image: yes]

We are seeing significantly more editing and improved voting.

The new "close" tab in `/review` also increased the amount of closing. And we are seeing more bad content get deleted.

[image: close/delete]

I also had some more stats about review at: [Is the marked state for reviewed questions bleeding across to late answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111941/is-the-marked-state-for-reviewed-questions-bleeding-across-to-late-answers/112198#comment291458_112198)

The increase answer deletion does directly correlate with us catching more spam and bad answers.

We are seeing close to **4000** reviews a day all by users that have `Strunk & White`.

---

Bottom line, content is getting more improvements, people are participating more in janitorial work. Only big pain point is that we need a few more mods on SO, something that will be solved by the election.

Comment: Awesome news, and thank you for such a comprehensive answer. I figured the diamond people would have this information.

Comment: And I have the impression (not backed by hard data, I should say) that I’m seeing more questions being closed without them needing to be closed. In fact, on the tags I monitor, some of the people that have (wrongly IMO) voted to close do not have any profile-visible knowledge of the contents.

Comment: specific examples @Bavarious ... we will adjust areas to compensate

Comment: @Bavarious also ... keep in mind, my main goal around /review has been ... improve content on the site, that is the reason we require users have strunk & white even to participate in the process

Comment: @waffles I recall these two: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8046541/557219 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/8057774/557219 (this was reopened after I talked to Moshe about it).

Comment: I understand the goal of /review and the Reviewer badge, I can certainly see that reviewing activity has increased, and I realise that overall it’s more benefits than drawbacks.

Comment: @Bavarious you got to admit both those questions were pretty rubbish before the edits

Comment: @waffles Agreed, but IMO if poorly written questions are salvageable it’s preferable to edit them before voting to close them. This one was almost closed as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8045929/557219

Comment: One thing these data don't reveal, but I suspect must be true, is that if there is *more* reviewing going on, necessary clean-up is happening faster. I used to be able to sit here in the Australian time zone and start picking off the spam and not-an-answers in bulk as the continents to my west started their mornings. Others are getting there first now.

Comment: And yet another closed question, this time with a binding vote by a moderator: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8169430/557219 Only the first voter knows Cocoa.

Comment: @Bavarious flag that, leaving a comment to Kev may not reach him (in future)

Comment: @waffles Good to know. I ended up flagging it because I read your comment before the edit. Anyway, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Maybe the review tab should also show quesions with tags the reviewer have got some upvotes in...

Comment: Any idea what that spike was between 23 Sep and 1 Oct?

Comment: @JasonPlank - Around September 12, the number of delete votes for users was increased significantly, from the 5 we used to have: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79015/now-that-20k-users-can-delete-answers-should-we-increase-the-number-of-daily-de/105876#105876 .  That's close to the start of the spike around Sept. 16.  There's also the return of students to classes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106611/is-there-anything-to-be-done-about-the-arrival-of-september